# How can Windows application specific network traffic be redirected to a proxy server running on a Virtual Machine?

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualization

I would like to redirect all network traffic originating from a specific application running in Windows 7 to a virtual machine guest OS loaded with proxy and network monitoring software. The virtual machine is running Ubuntu as a guest OS within VirtualBox.

How would I go about making the guest virtual machine accessible on my network (or even to my Windows machine), and then redirecting application specific network traffic to be processed by the proxy running on the guest OS?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What is you current network configuration (host, guest and beyond).  What have you tried already (`route`)?  Where are you getting stuck.

Comment: Now I have nothing, but I'm planning to set up Ubuntu with [netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem) configured on virtual machine (VirtualBox on Windows 7 host) to test how my application behaves under non-perfect network conditions.

Comment: That was a mighty edit @nathan

Comment: But it isn't exactly what I want to do - I mean, doesn't proxy change the sender IP? I don't want that. I want to **route** (exactly how was it stated in original version of the question) application traffic through virtual machine and not use a proxy. It would be simple if I created another vm for the app and set up previous vm as a router for this vm, but for various reasons I can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your guest OS's Network Adapter in 'Bridged' mode in either VirtualBox or VMware so that the guest will connect directly to your router with a separate MAC address and internal IP address. You can then configure your router to assign a static IP to the guest VM and it will operate as if it were an independent machine on your network. Alternatively you can configure port forwarding through NAT, whereby you would reach the VM at `localhost:<forwarded port>`. For detailed instructions on how to do this see [How to Forward Ports to a Virtual Machine and Use It as a Server](http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/) on howtogeek.

Once the guest OS is visible to your host OS you can redirect traffic application specific traffic to the VM with [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/) (trialware). I haven't tested it but I don't think this would alter the originating IP address. You may however need to configure [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) on your guest machine so that it is able to route traffic through netem in your specific use case. You may find [Forwarding ports to guests in libvirt / KVM](https://serverfault.com/questions/170079/forwarding-ports-to-guests-in-libvirt-kvm) useful reading.

If you wish to **route** *all* traffic through the VM see [Adding a TCP/IP Route to the Windows Routing Table](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/).